# Changing tabs color of excel sheets with Java JXL library

Tags: java, excel, jxl

The question I have is, is it possible to change the color of the tabs in an excel by programming them with the JXL library?. I can’t attach code since I don’t even know how I would do it. Thank you very much and greetings!

Comment: The only thing I know about this topic: It is possible with apache poi, but no idea about JXL...

Comment: And what should I do with apache poi? @deHaar

Comment: You can [`setTabColor(XSSFColor color)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#setTabColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-)...